# List view in Apps section of iTunes?

Tags: itunes, macos, books

I've got two mac and both are running last version of OS X and iTunes but there's a little difference that I hate and I don't know how to solve:

These are the possible views of the Apps section in iTunes of one Mac:

[image: All; iPhone/iPod touch; iPad; List; Updates]

…and these on the other one:

[image: All; iPhone/iPod touch; iPad; Updates]

Trouble is that list view would be very useful and I don't know hot to get it on the second Mac too - is there somebody who has an idea?

EDIT: Same trouble even in Mavericks, even in Movies and Books (in iBook), always only in a Mac, on the other Mac everything works fine...

Comment: well, it "should" be there. which exact versions of itunes, ibooks and os x do you have an both Macs? Try to delete iTunes and reinstall it.

Comment: Good catch! Please post the solution as answer, so this question appears answered throughout the site. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iTunes (in menù bar) > Preferences, then General > Show list views for all media.
This setting works for iBook too!